# What replaced the ContentFormControllerSubscriber class?

Tags: 8, event-subscribers

In the past, there was a [`ContentFormControllerSubscriber`](http://code.projspace.com/medhamsh/drupal/raw/99b9a6a579bac7cf161b51df0f95b044e7ab125c/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/ContentFormControllerSubscriber.php) class in Drupal, but [there is no track of it](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/8/search/ContentFormControllerSubscriber) anymore; [the change records](https://www.drupal.org/list-changes/drupal/published?keywords_description=ContentFormControllerSubscriber&to_branch=&version=&created_op=%3E%3D&created[value]=&created[min]=&created[max]=) don't report anything about that class too.

The reason I am looking for that class replacement is that I noticed the Chaos tools module using [a similar class](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/ctools/tree/src/EventSubscriber/WizardControllerSubscriber.php?h=8.x-3.x) to alter the requests passed to Drupal, and I was wondering if the priority (29) used in the `getSubscribedEvents()` method of those classes is still sufficient to alter the request before it is too late, and not doing it too early.
I guess the Chaos tools module used that value because it was used from Drupal core too; I am assuming there was a good reason to do so.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/2368275 discusses a change to that class, and towards the bottom it's noted that its name doesn't make sense any more and _We can clean up the naming at any time._. Looks like they did, but can't find a reference for what it changed to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was renamed once or twice, but https://www.drupal.org/node/2613034 moved the actual code from an event subscriber to a route enhancer. See `\Drupal\Core\Routing\Enhancer\FormRouteEnhancer` for the current approach.

Good event subscribers will document how they determined what priority to use, it could have been random or very carefully picked.

See CTools' `\Drupal\ctools\EventSubscriber\WizardControllerSubscriber` which still uses 29.